# How to crop Image?

Tags: ios, ipad

I am developing an iPad application by which i am using image context to draw. I am adding one more image view on top of the drawing context for resizing the image. When i done zooming the image i need to crop the zoomed image for the common area in both of the images and draw the cropped image to the base drawing image.

Any help would be appreciable.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following method:

```
-(UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage *)img fromRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    if (scale > 1.0f) {
        rect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x * scale,
                          rect.origin.y * scale,
                          rect.size.width * scale,
                          rect.size.height * scale);
    }

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(img.CGImage, rect);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:scale orientation:img.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return result;
}
```